# Reconstructing a string from random samples

Tags: computer-science

What is known about the following problem?

> Reconstruct a string $\sigma$ of known length $n$ over a known
>   alphabet $\Sigma$ from a collection of uniformly and independently
>   chosen $k$-long subsequences of $\sigma$ where $k$ is fixed between
>   $0$ and $n$.

*Recall that a $k$-long subsequence of $\sigma=\langle \sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\rangle$ is a sequence $\langle \sigma_{\varphi(1)},\dots,\sigma_{\varphi(k)}\rangle$ where $\varphi$ is an increasing function from $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.*

Comment: Cross-posted from http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27189

Comment: So if each string is encoded as a vector in a finite field, then given several projections (hence, linear measurements) you are seeking to reconstruct the original. Sounds like a finite field version of a generic *inverse problem* ; I wonder which of the standard http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/OptimalRecovery.pdf  "signal recovery from random projections" ideas extend....

Comment: Presumably you don't know which $\phi$ corresponds to a given subsequence, otherwise the problem is trivial (you'd just have to wait until you've seen all the characters of the string).  I think that is the difference between this situation and the usual "signal recovery from random projections", where the projections are known.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: In that case, this becomes more like a "blind deconvolution" problem :-) --- also, as a side note, in the usual signal recovery case, one wishes to recover the signal from a much smaller number of measurements / projections than the trivial "wait until I've seen all" version!

Comment: Seems hard to reconstruct the string $a^x b a^y$, where $x,y \gg k$. Only a small fraction of samples will include the $b$, and you need enough of these to reliably estimate $x$ and $y$ based on the average position of $b$ in such samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the string $\sigma$, for any word $x$ of length $k$ the probability $P_{n,k}(\sigma, x)$ 
that a randomly chosen $k$-long subsequence matches $x$ can be computed, e.g. using
$$ P_{n,k}(\sigma,x) =  \dfrac{k}{n} \delta_{\sigma_1, x_1} P_{n-1,k-1}(\sigma',x') + \left(1 - \dfrac{k}{n}\right) P_{n-1,k}(\sigma',x)$$
where $\sigma'$ and $x'$ are $\sigma$ and $x$ respectively with the first symbol removed.  If the distributions for different $\sigma$ are different, in principle we can take enough samples to classify $\sigma$ with high probability.
But if two $\sigma$'s have the same distribution, we can't distinguish them.

For example, take $n=4$, $k=2$ and the alphabet $\{0,1\}$, Here are all the 
$P_{4,2}$:

$$  \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} &[0,0]&[0,1]&[1,0]&[1,1]
\\ [0,0,0,0]&1&0&0&0\\ [0,0,0,1]&1
/2&1/2&0&0\\ [0,0,1,0]&1/2&1/3&1/6&0
\\ [0,0,1,1]&1/6&2/3&0&1/6\\ [0,1,0
,0]&1/2&1/6&1/3&0\\ [0,1,0,1]&1/6&1/2&1/6&1/6
\\ [0,1,1,0]&1/6&1/3&1/3&1/6\\ [0,
1,1,1]&0&1/2&0&1/2\\ [1,0,0,0]&1/2&0&1/2&0
\\ [1,0,0,1]&1/6&1/3&1/3&1/6\\ [1,0
,1,0]&1/6&1/6&1/2&1/6\\ [1,0,1,1]&0&1/3&1/6&1/2
\\ [1,1,0,0]&1/6&0&2/3&1/6\\ [1,1,0
,1]&0&1/6&1/3&1/2\\ [1,1,1,0]&0&0&1/2&1/2
\\ [1,1,1,1]&0&0&0&1\end {array} \right] 
$$

Note that $\sigma = [0,1,1,0]$ and $\sigma = [ 1,0,0,1]$ both have the same
distribution.  So these two cannot be distinguished by their distributions of $2$-long subsequences.

EDIT: For another example, for $n=7$ and $k=3$, $\sigma = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]$
and $\sigma = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]$ can't be distinguished by their distributions of $3$-long subsequences.  But for $n=6$, all $\sigma \in \{0,1\}^6$ can be distinguished
by their distributions of $3$-long subsequences.

Comment: Debruijn words would also provide examples that could not be distinguished.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger De Bruijn sequences have to do with consecutive subsequences, which is not the case here.
I see no reason why two De Bruijn sequences should have the same distribution of $k$-long non-consecutive subsequences.